# if "make -j2" and "make" can accelerate make process and solve all make sequence related issue?

Tags: c++, makefile

if "make -j2" and "make" can accelerate make process and solve all make sequence related issue?

sometimes when I want to speed up the make process, I had to add -j to make command. but after I using such command opts, some project's some cpp can't be made successfully due to make sequence 's unordered. So I "make" it again without any command opts to solve these erros.

In brief, I use make -j2 to speed up the make process and use make without opts to solve the issues occured in make -j2. All of thess are to speed up the make process.

My question is that if any issue existed after "make -j2" and "make"?

Comment: Can you show us your Makefile? As long as all dependencies are set correctly in the Makefile, -j2 shouldn't cause any errors. However If a dependency missing in the Makefile, it may happen that with one job the dependency is accidendly fullfilled, while it causes in error with more jobs.

Comment: do you mean if make -j2 caused error, it is the wrong for the make file self?

Comment: If you're asking whether it is possible to write a Makefile such that doing a "make -j2" and then a "make" could leave things in a bad state, my feeling would be yes, it's probably possible.  If you're asking if it's true about your particular case, how would we know without seeing your case?

Answer (score 1):

They don't solve anything ever. They just honor your makefile.  If your makefile is broken and has incorrect dependencies than applying more than one process/thread to make isn't going to work reliably.  (As you've discovered)

You have to take the time to make sure that your dependencies are laid out properly so that it knows what it can and can't compile at the same time, what depends on what, and which files are shared in multiple compilation units.

Done properly the only difference between make -j 1, -j 2 and -j 20 is that more cores are used and the job should get done faster.

And for further reference, I don't even pass it as an argument.
`export MAKEFLAGS="-j 20"`  is essentially in my environment.